# Facebook share count not working - new API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A few days ago facebook stopped displaying share count information in graph. how is it currently downloaded to display on a page in php?

always after entering this link, there was also information about the number of shares and currently there is no: https://graph.facebook.com/https://demotywatory.pl/4922745/Dziecko-nie-wie-ze-to-rzezba-po-prostu-chce-pomoc

I want to display this information on my website. how to do it? please help

Comment: you should use a more specific headline for questions, the current one is quite random. i improved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This info is now provided under the `engagement` field of the `URL` object node.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/url

```
/?id={url}&fields=engagement
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdemotywatory.pl%2F4922745%2FDziecko-nie-wie-ze-to-rzezba-po-prostu-chce-pomoc%26fields%3Dengagement&version=v3.2

Comment: Make the API request, decode the JSON, access the property in the resulting data structure …

Comment: z jakiego url mam wyciągnąć json 
wpisze https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt2015381%2F

to w przegladarce pokazuje sie tylko pole id a nie ma share count. please help

Comment: how to make an api request?

Comment: Same way as you already did with the link you had inside your question …

Comment: (And the Get Code button in Graph API Explorer already provides code for that particular request for several language/libraries.)

Comment: Thank you for help, but I do not understand a bit. I have to give a link with the questions but no longer displays the sharing and sharing counting do not download by the app but there does not fit the entire link only part of the for example ?Id  https://moving2canada.com/express-entry-draw/&fields=engagement

and I do not know what link to give in php to use json. how to click on "get code" and select php there is no address :(

please help

Comment: You need to submit the request in Graph API Explorer first, only then the Get Code button becomes active. The PHP code it suggests is based on the assumption that you use the PHP SDK though; if you are not using that, but are just making an HTTP yourself, then use the URL from the cURL example instead. (But the access token included there will expire, so you need to replace that with your own.)

Comment: I apologize for my English but I really care about doing it but I still can not.

You need to submit the request in Graph API Explorer first. OK, I did it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdemotywatory.pl%2F4922745%2FDziecko-nie-wie-ze-to-rzezba-po-prostu-chce-pomoc%26fields%3Dengagement&version=v3.2

Comment: Now, I click "get code". in "php sdk" I have something like this:

try {
   // Returns and `FacebookFacebookResponse` object
   $ response = $ fb-> get (
     /,
     '{-Access token}'
   );
} catch (FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $ e) {
   echo 'Graph returned an error:'. $ E-> getMessage ();
   exit;
} catch (FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $ e) {
   echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error:'. $ E-> getMessage ();
   exit;
}
$ graphNode = $ response-> getGraphNode ();

Comment: How to use it? here there is not even the address of the page from which he wants to download the share count. Please help

Comment: As I said, that would be PHP code to use together with the PHP SDK. You need to go read up on some basics of using the Graph API, that really is too broad to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

Its working like below with facebook's app_id & app_secret.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id={URL}&fields=engagement&access_token={your-app_id}|{your-app_secret}
```

output :

> ```
> {
>   "engagement": {
>     "reaction_count": 5,
>     "comment_count": 3,
>     "share_count": 60,
>     "comment_plugin_count": 0
>   },
>   "id": "https://www.testing.com"
> }
> ```